# ListArray with Bean from JSTL

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl, javabeans

I have an Array that is populated.I have tried several ways to get it always results in nullpointer. I have tried to iterate through with index in JSP and still I get only one row.

I can print the content of it in Java

```
List<Bean> ListAches = new ArrayList<Bean>();
for(int i=0;i<ListAches .size();i++){
            System.out.println(ListAches.get(i).getFirst());
            System.out.println(ListAches.get(i).getSecon());
}
```

I am trying to print it out in the JSP page

```
<c:forEach var="Bean" items="${ListAches}" >
 <td> ${Bean.first}</td>
    <td> ${Bean.second}</td>
        </c:forEach>
```

I get an error nullpointer can't recognize "first"
When I change it to `${Bean.get(i).first}`
It prints out the value correctly of only the first row and does not iterate. 
I have tried several ways to get it always results in nullpointer.I have tried to iterate through with index in JSP and still I get only one row.

Comment: So, you're trying to tell that `<c:forEach>` didn't run at all? How exactly did you install JSTL? Do all other JSTL things work fine?

Comment: I have included in the jsp too. Just can't get <c:forEach> to work.
 <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

Comment: I take back. I just added this code for testing the loop and it also does not work. It just prints out item

<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   Item <c:out value="${i}"/><p>
</c:forEach>

Comment: So, you expected the `c` taglib to work when you declare only the `fn` taglib? Where did you read/learn how to install and configure JSTL?

Comment: add bean's field please. Maybe getSecon() is secon field. ${Bean.secon}